# Github webhooks suddenly stopped auto-pulling (Webhooks & cPanel Git Version Control)

Tags: php, git, github, cpanel, webhooks

Everything ran fan for a few years, but the site suddenly stopped auto-pulling changes to our github repository

We have a site running on Bluehost, and we set up our server repositories via cPanel's Git Version Control.  When we manually update via the "Update from remote repository" button, the changes made to our Github repositories sync perfectly fine.

We set up some webhooks to monitor changes and automatically pull them. I can't remember if these were required or a failed separate attempt from Git Version Control, but here's the relevant file:

**/webhooks/git-post-receive.php**

```
<?php
/* Use in the "Post-Receive URLs" section of your GitHub repo.
* HAD TO:
  - Set up webhook in GitHub
  - Set up secret key between the two
  - Exclude this directory from htaccess
*/

$now = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());
$secret = "SECRET";
//file_put_contents("./log.txt","New log file at $now");

if ( $_POST['payload'] ) {  //NOTE: This works with x-www-form-urlencoded but NOT json encoded

  // Headers deliveried from GitHub
  $signature = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_HUB_SIGNATURE'];
  $branch = "";
  $email = "";
  $subject = "";
  $message = "";

  // CHECK password hash
  if ($signature) {
    $hash = "sha1=".hash_hmac('sha1', file_get_contents("php://input"), $secret); // Create hash of secret key
    if (strcmp($signature, $hash) == 0) {
      $postBody = $_POST['payload'];
      $payload = json_decode($postBody);

      $branch = substr($payload->ref, strrpos($payload->ref, '/') + 1);
      switch($branch){
        case "master":
          $email = "eng@playbookproducts.com";
          chdir('/home/pbhqcom/public_html/internal/');
          break;
        case "austin":
          $email = "austin@playbookproducts.com";
          chdir('/home/pbhqcom/public_html/test-austin/');
          break;
        case "teague":
          $email = "teague@playbookproducts.com";
          chdir('/home/pbhqcom/public_html/test-teague/');
          break;
        default:
          echo "BRANCH ERROR: $branch not in git-post-receive.php switch()";
          die;
          break;

      }

      shell_exec( 'git reset --hard HEAD && git pull' );

      $subject = "[WEBHOOK] GitHub deployment to playbook-internal branch $branch";

      ob_start();
      var_dump($payload);
      $message = ob_get_clean();

      $sender = 'site@playbookproducts.com';
      $headers = 'From:' . $sender;
      mail(
        $email,
        $subject,
        $message,
        $headers
        );
    }
    echo "SUCCESS! $branch | $now";
  }else{
    echo "FAILURE: Keys did not match";
  }
}
?>

FILE: /webhooks/git-post-receive.php
```

Where should I be looking to figure out why it's not auto-pulling to our servers anymore?

Comment: Seems like this may related to Githubs recent RSA SSH host key changes: https://github.blog/2023-03-23-we-updated-our-rsa-ssh-host-key/

Comment: You have the log command commented out - if you uncomment it, then would that give more detail about why this is failing? The SSH host key change seems plausible but there isn't enough info here to tell if that's it or if something else is broken.